# Compiler that removes endless loops

Tags: software-development, c++

C++ has the "process guarantee", i.e. every thread has to make visible progress and [*visible* is defined](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/memory_model#Progress_guarantee).

The example is an endless loop in which case

> This allows the compilers to remove all loops that have no observable behavior, without having to prove that they would eventually terminate.

I am looking for a compiler that has implemented this behavior, i.e. simply removes endless loops such as

```
for(;;);
```

I would use this in trainings for C++ developers to demonstrate that such compilers really exist and "undefined behavior" is a dangerous thing to rely on.

I'm aware that such a compiler might not exist, because it's undefined behavior after all and instead of removing the loop, it could run a round of Tetris instead. Anyway, if you happen to know one, please suggest it.

I don't care about OS, price or C++ version at the moment.

Comment: Any particular version of C++? E.g. C++ 17

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica: no, any version is ok. I added that to the question

Comment: I am sorry that I don't have an answer, but I am marking this as a favo(u)rite.  `I would use this in trainings for C++ developers to demonstrate that such compilers really exist and "undefined behavior" is a dangerous thing to rely on`;  "undefined behavior"  === "here be dragons". Are you also teaching static code analysis? Or even compiler++ such as MISRA? I know that it is not the same thing, but it is well worth teaching. And I am sure you know of our suster site https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @MawgsaysreinstateMonica thanks. It seems I signed up there but forgot about it :-)

Comment: Lol :-) It seems perfect for you.